# Android - separating List strings

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am retrieving the string data from an element clicked in my listview.

The element has two rows, one named "current" and one named "name". 
in my listItemOnClick(), i am getting the item that was clicked, and then doing toString() on it. what i am getting is something like this:

```
{current=SOMETHING, name=SOMETHING}
```

My question is how do i separate these? Here is my onclick code:

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String current = o.toString();

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.check)).setText(current);
}
```

I want to disply only the current for example. Thanks!

**EDIT**

My List Variables:

```
    static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listItems = 
        new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();;
SimpleAdapter adapter;
```

Creating the list:

```
       for(int i=0; i<num_enter; i++){
    final int gi = i;
    adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.custom_row_view,new String[]{"name", "current"},  new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp.put("name", name[i]);
    temp.put("current", "Value: " + Integer.toString(current[i]));
    listItems.add(temp);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: What sort of objects are actually in the list? The best thing would be to get a more-specific class than `Object` for whatever `o` is.

Comment: In the list there is only text. I added some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it that way (ugly and prone to future error when / if the format changes) - add error checks in case the string does not have the right format:

```
String s = "{current=CURRENT, name=NAME}";
s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1); //removes { and }
String[] items = s.split(",");
String current = items[0].split("=")[1]; //CURRENT
String name = items[1].split("=")[1]; //NAME
```

Following your edit, it seems that o is a Map so you could also write (much better):

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String current = map.get("current");
String name = map.get("name");
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow, everyone is taking the long way round.  Get the data directly from the view.  The View v in this case is your layout row, so using that you can find the individual textviews using `findViewById` and the get the text from them.  Using your code it would be like this:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    TextView nameTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Text1);
    TextView currentTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Text2);
    String name = nameTxt.getText().toString();
    String current = currentTxt.getText().toString();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It should not be very difficult:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String current = o.toString();

// first remove the first and last brace
current = current.substring(1,current.length()-1);
// then split on a comma
String[] elements = current.split(",");
// now for every element split on =
String[] subelements = elements[0].split("=");
String key1 = subelements[0];
String value1 = subelements[1];

subelements = elements[1].split("=");
String key2 = subelements[0];
String value2 = subelements[1];


((TextView) findViewById(R.id.check)).setText(current);
}
```